# find only one entry from database with less than condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to find only one entry from db which is less than other row

i have written this query , is there other method than this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  users 
WHERE birthdate < 1420239600
```

It will return all users whose birthdate  is less than 1320239600 
but i need to show only one row like 1320239599 not 1 to 1320239599

**edit**

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE birthdate < 13
ORDER BY birthdate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

it returns 1 as it is less among all but requirement is it should return 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT * 
FROM  users 
WHERE birthdate < 1420239600
ORDER BY birthdate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**MSSQL**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM  users 
WHERE birthdate < 1420239600
ORDER BY birthdate DESC
```

This will select the first entry only

Comment: it returns 1420239555 but what i want is 1420239559

Comment: you just need to change the value in that case

Comment: @Arijiit Mukherjee what value you are saying

Comment: @software you should be using proper date format I should be suggesting

Answer (score 1):

I think the safest option would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE birthdate < 1320239600
ORDER BY birthdate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You had the less than operator the wrong way round.
Arijit's answer is only valid for MS SQL Server or MS Access, this statement using ORDER BY and LIMIT is the equivalent in MySQL.

Comment: what's the difference between your and mine ans :)

Comment: @chriswilks  it returns the value which is less among other record but requirement is it should return 1320239599 not 1 for example if data is from 1 to 10 and  if i want less than 5 so it should return 4 not 1

Comment: @software thats what the 'desc' ordering is for

Answer (score 0):

Use this one instead :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE birthdate = (SELECT MIN(birthdate) FROM users) LIMIT 1;
```